# How to determine probability of score when selecting from pool of values?

Tags: sampling, descriptive-statistics

The question seems simple but I just can't solve it.

I have twelve test scores and three are to be picked at random to determine the overall test grade. How can I calculate the probability of my final grade based on three randomly picked tests from the pool?

The test scores are as follows:

```
100=4
33=2
66=6

100 33 66 66 66 100 66 66 100 66 33 100
```

Would running a simulation be the simplest solution? Is there a good solution?

Comment: Is this for a class assignment?

Comment: No, I happen to be the only one in the office that has a BS instead of a BA and have taken any math/statistics related course in the last 10 years. All quantitative issues are sourced to me.

Actually this was a question posed by my co-worker who is worried about his grades in a Masters program. I am simply  interested in how this can be solved. I ended up running a simple simulation in Excel 10,000 times to get the probabilities. I am wondering whether there is a better way to do this instead of a brute Excel method.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need an exact figure, simulation is, as you've discovered, easy to do and a good approach to getting an answer.

But if you wanted something more exact, you could write yourself a short program to iterate through all $\frac{12!}{9!} = 1320$ ways three test scores could be chosen.  Each triple is equally likely to represent your final grade as any other, so the probability of a final grade being $X$ is the portion of triples with average grade $X$.

Finally, if you don't feel like writing any code, you could power through a smaller number of cases and model the sampling as a [multivariate hypergeometric distribution](http://www.randomservices.org/random/urn/MultiHypergeometric.html).  With this distribution you can calculate the probability of your final grade consisting of $n_{100}$ 100s, $n_{33}$ 33s, and $n_{66}$ 66s as

$$\frac{\binom{4}{n_{100}}\binom{2}{n_{33}}\binom{6}{n_{66}}}{\binom{12}{3}}$$

and go from there.

Comment: 2nd paragraph:  Shouldn't you divide by 3! as well, yielding 220 combinations (not permutations)?

Comment: There are indeed 220 combinations, and you could iterate over them if you like, too.  Whichever you find easier to write your program for, I suppose.